# Spring Cloud Stream Kafka Consumer Test

Tags: apache-kafka-streams, spring-cloud-stream

I am trying to setup test as suggested here at  GitHub [a link](https://github.com/spring-cloud/spring-cloud-stream-binder-kafka/blob/master/spring-cloud-stream-binder-kafka-streams/src/test/java/org/springframework/cloud/stream/binder/kafka/streams/integration/KafkaStreamsBinderWordCountIntegrationTests.java)

```
        Map<String, Object> senderProps = KafkaTestUtils.producerProps(embeddedKafka);
    DefaultKafkaProducerFactory<Integer, String> pf = new DefaultKafkaProducerFactory<>(senderProps);
    try {
        KafkaTemplate<Integer, String> template = new KafkaTemplate<>(pf, true);
        template.setDefaultTopic("words");
        template.sendDefault("foobar");

    --> ConsumerRecord<String, String> cr = KafkaTestUtils.getSingleRecord(consumer, "output");
        log.debug(cr);
    }
    finally {
        pf.destroy();
    }
```

Where StreamProcessor is set to

```
@StreamListener
    @SendTo("output")
    public KStream<?, WordCount> process(@Input("input") KStream<Object, String> input) {

        return input.map((key, value) -> new KeyValue<>(value, new WordCount(value, 10, new Date(), new Date())));
    }
```

--> line never consumes messages which to my mind should be on topic "output" due to the fact that @Streamprocessor has @SendTo("output")

- I want to be able to test stream processed messages.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to consume from the actual topic that your `output` is bound to.
Do you have a configuration for `spring.cloud.stream.bindings.output.destination`? That should be the value that you need to use. If you don't set that, the default will be the same as the binding - `output` in this case.

Comment: I have tried with private EmbeddedKafkaBroker embeddedKafka = new EmbeddedKafkaBroker(1, true, new String[] { "words", "input", "output", "counts" });

Comment: .web(WebApplicationType.NONE).run("--server.port=0",
"--spring.jmx.enabled=false",
"--spring.cloud.stream.bindings.input.destination=words",
"--spring.cloud.stream.bindings.output.destination=counts",